# ANOVA test with good f & p values & small R-squared value

Tags: return-value, anova

im using a one way ANOVA test to  measure the degree of fittness or in other words the difference between experimental data & other data i predicted. i conducted the test on Minitab software & got acceptable values for both F & P values while R2 value was small 0.30 % as shown  below :

One-way ANOVA: ANN Sr, Exp.Sr

Source:  DF=1  ,  SS=  0.824   , MS=  0.824   ,   F =1.89 ,     P=0.170

S = 0.6605 ,  R-Sq = 0.30%   , R-Sq(adj) = 0.14%

according to f & p values (1.89 & 0.17 respectively ) i would say that my predicted data are accurate & there is no difference between experimental & predicted data.

My question is:

can this small value of R-sq=0.30% affect my decision ???can i reject the data i predicted & say there is a significance difference from experimental data even though f&p values are acceptable???.

Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and should have been asked on [Cross Validated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342651/anova-test-with-good-f-p-values-small-r-squared-value).